# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).slideDown/slideUp is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have a simple image gallery where the figcaption is hidden on each image.  Here is the HTML:

```
<figure>
<img src="gallery/reef2.jpg" width="400" height="285" alt="Another beautiful example of the Great Barrier Reef"/>
<figcaption>Another cracking shot of the reef from Mark. <span>[Photographer: Mark Willams]</span></figcaption>
</figure>
```

And here is the jQuery for it:

```
$("figcaption").hide();
$("figure").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).find("figcaption").slideDown('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("figcaption").slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, when I hover over and away from the image nothing happens.  When I open Chrome's developer tools, I can see that on hover I get this message:

"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).slideDown is not a function"

and when I hover away from the image, I get this message:

"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).slideUp is not a function"

I am not sure why slideDown and slideUp are not working as they should since the figcaption is hidden.  Before using slideDown and slideUp, I was using show and hide which worked perfectly.  Please help me understand how I can get slideDown and SlideUp working properly.

Comment: my guess is you are using jQuery 3 slim

Comment: @epascarello - looks like it's the full library she's using.

Comment: @bhansa and I bet you used the wrong version of jQuery

Comment: @Adam that is not the OPs code, someone added it.... Half tempted to roll it back since it is not what OP had.

Comment: You're right, why would someone edit a question with no idea what the OP's actual code is, beyond me.

Comment: @bhansa - you should know better. We need to see OP's original code in question, not something you've added to resolve it.

Comment: I am using jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js.

Comment: And slim does not support animations....

Comment: Then that is your problem, @BrittanyDanielleSmith, it's likely the Slim version doesn't include the functionality. Try switching to the full jQuery library.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like your code works as written.  Are you sure you are including jQuery, and that the version you are including has `slideUp` and `slideDown`?

```js
$("figcaption").hide();
$("figure").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).find("figcaption").slideDown('slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("figcaption").slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
<figcaption>Another cracking shot of the reef from Mark. <span>[Photographer: Mark Willams]</span></figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: I am using jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js.  Perhaps that's the issue- I might be using the wrong version of jQuery?

Comment: yeah, just remove `.slim` from it and it should work

Comment: UPDATE:  I changed to jquery-3.3.1.min.js, and it now works as intended!  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes on your answer. A user edited the OP's original question to include a library that she never had in her code. This answer is correct.